# Read Gmail inbox resulting in 'Too many login failures' error

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am trying to read gmail inbox using following code:

```php
    set_time_limit(4000);
    // Connect to gmail
    $imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'usenamer@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password';
    // try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($imapPath,$username,$password,NULL,1) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
    $output = '';
    foreach($emails as $mail) {
        $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox,$mail);
        $output .= $headerInfo->subject.'<br/>';
        $output .= $headerInfo->toaddress.'<br/>';
        $output .= $headerInfo->date.'<br/>';
        $output .= $headerInfo->fromaddress.'<br/>';
        $output .= $headerInfo->reply_toaddress.'<br/>';
        $emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$mail);
        if(!isset($emailStructure->parts)) {
             $output .= imap_body($inbox, $mail, FT_PEEK);
        } else {
            //    
        }
       echo $output;
       $output = '';
    }
    // colse the connection
    imap_expunge($inbox);
    imap_close($inbox);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure) [1] => Too many login failures)

Comment: See your error URL and read it. Might be you are sending wrong password or there will be `2-Step Verification` enabled on account.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap   OR  https://arjunphp.com/reading-emails-from-gmail-using-php-imap/

Comment: I tried those codes but still same error..

Comment: 2-Step Verification is not enabled and I have also turned ON Access for less secure apps

Comment: quick question... IIRC, you have to make the connection via a ssl secure page. (could be wrong) but maybe this(??) i seem to recall playing around with this a couple years ago and that was an issue for me.

Comment: I have SSL enabled already in my apache settings.. I am trying retrieve gmail inbox using my local server (Wamp) . Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Change Gmail accounting setting:-

Enable IMAP.

Status: IMAP is enabled[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed by allowing access for "If You’re signing in from a new location or device" in my Gmail settings

Answer (score 0):

and also turn **ON** less secure apps [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps):

`Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.`

reference: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229#zippy=%2Ci-cant-sign-in-to-my-email-client)

Comment: Less secure apps are not available any more. From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Does not apply to Google Workspace or Google Cloud Identity customers yet.

Comment: @mikiqex Less secure apps are still available (with few changes). Just require to enable 2FA and generate [APP PASSWORD](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).